# .vimrc script for opening a web link from VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to setup .vimrc, such that I can open a weblink from inside the vim editor. Any good examples?

Comment: What platform are you using? Do you have a preferred browser, or do mean displaying the webpage itself inside Vim?

Comment: you want to load the webpage html codes in your vim? or you want to open the weblink in browser?

Comment: I am using unix shell,
I want to open weblink in the default browser. can be any mozilla firefox, safari.

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use? In Gnome terminal and URXVT, you get that feature for free.

Answer (score 2):

The [Universal Text Linking](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=293) (utl.vim) plugin can do that (among many other powerful things). For example, I use it as a way do document my .vimrc with relevant links or help topics:

```
" Jump to last position in the file, see <url:vimhelp:last-position-jump>
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

After installing it, read the help (`:h utl`), it is very well explained, with an embedded tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the [open-browser.vim - Open URI with your favorite browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133) plugin.

Comment: This plugin is great. But it seems that the `gx` mapping provided does not work. I have to use another mapping to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in Ubuntu (either vim or gvim) using the following to call a system command:

```
:call system('firefox www.google.com')
```

Note you can achieve the same using simply

```
:!firefox www.google.com
```

but this temporarily hijacks the Vim window.

Answer (score 0):

openurl.vim : open a url in a default browser

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3291